# How can I stop printing a delimiter when the content starts a new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm printing a long horizontal list, which starts a new line when it reaches the end of its div, and objects are seperated by a comma:

```
<% Page.all.each_with_index do |p| %>
  <%= p.name %>
  <% if index + 1 < Page.count %>
    &nbsp-&nsbp
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Right now, it prints like this if `Page.count == 18`:

```
page - page - page - page - page - page -
page - page - page - page - page - page -
page - page - page - page - page - page
```

so there is an ugly delimiter at the end of all but the last lines. Is there a way to prevent the delimiter from being printed if the end of the div is reached, so it would print like this?

```
page - page - page - page - page - page
page - page - page - page - page - page
page - page - page - page - page - page
```

Comment: Are you required to use hyphens like that?

Comment: This is really an HTML and CSS question.

Comment: @muistooshort It doesn't necessarily need to be hyphens. I'm just asking about general delimiters.

Comment: I'd opt to say something like `<span class="whatever"><%= p.name %></span>` and then set up the `.whatever` CSS to make them look nice.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to control that without actually making the lines wrap yourself, eg. by having new divs for each row.